# Hiking vs climb a mountain

Tags: terminology

I was suggested using the term "hiking" instead of "go climb a mountain" when trying to describe a tour in which we go to a mountain and climb up for exercises.

As I understand, hiking is the activity of taking long walks.

what term can be used to serve as the sense, where you go on a travel to climb a mountain for fun/exercises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I upvoted your question because it provides a good example of how words can have overlapping meanings, and we must rely on context to determine which meaning is intended.

As I type this now, a couple people have already left feedback saying that *climb* implies specialized equipment and technical difficulty, while *hike* implies a more relaxed amble. While this distinction isn't wrong, I feel like it also oversimplifies your problem and fails to give your question the detailed answer it deserves.

Most words in English have multiple meanings and nuances, and can be adapted to various uses. While it's true that *climb* can imply using your hands or special ropes and belaying equipment, that isn't always the case. For example, when Doyle wrote in one of his Sherlock Holmes stories, "Gregson **climbed** the stair to arrest this desperate murderer," no one imagines Gregson using ropes, special boots, or safety harnesses. And when a [news article](http://www.spokesman.com/stories/2010/feb/18/extended-adventure/) says, "Byrd recalled trekking through western China on the way to **hike** K2," we don't expect to read about a walk in the park by someone carrying little more than a water bottle and some trail mix.

In the context of mountaineering, both *hike* and *climb* can be used to describe either perilous ascents or upward recreational strolls. My daughter enjoys *rock climbing* as a hobby, but I can still find plenty of images like this one on Google using terms such as "hike up the ridge".

[image]

If you are trying to make sure the listener understands you are going up a mountain for fun or exercise, I don't think choosing the "right" word between *hike* and *climb* is a surefire way to do the trick, as either word can be used for that purpose. It would be pedantic to correct someone and say, "You shouldn't have said *climb*; you should have said *hike*," and such talk wouldn't win you many points among a community of outdoor recreation enthusiasts.

That all said, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiking) has some interesting notes about verbiage that might be useful:

> In the United States, Canada, the Republic of Ireland, and United Kingdom, *hiking* means walking outdoors on a trail, or off trail, for recreational purposes. A *day hike* refers to a hike that can be completed in a single day. However, in the United Kingdom, the word *walking* is also used, as well as *rambling*, while walking in mountainous areas is called *hillwalking*. In Northern England, Including the Lake District and Yorkshire Dales, *fellwalking* describes hill or mountain walks, as fell is the common word for both features there.
>
> Hiking sometimes involves *bushwhacking* and is sometimes referred to as such. This specifically refers to difficult walking through dense forest, undergrowth, or bushes, where forward progress requires pushing vegetation aside. In extreme cases of bushwhacking, where the vegetation is so dense that human passage is impeded, a machete is used to clear a pathway. The Australian term *bushwalking* refers to both on and off-trail hiking. Common terms for hiking used by New Zealanders are *tramping* (particularly for overnight and longer trips), *walking* or *bushwalking*. *Trekking* is the preferred word used to describe multi-day hiking in the mountainous regions of India, Pakistan, Nepal, North America, South America, Iran and in the highlands of East Africa. Hiking a long-distance trail from end-to-end is also referred to as *trekking* and as *thru-hiking* in some places. In North America, multi-day hikes, usually with camping, are referred to as *backpacking*.

Comment: I love this answer. It explains the difference between definitions quite clearly.

Answer (score 0):

- **to climb a mountain** is something very extreme done using special equipment. This mostly refers to an almost vertical movement or to very steep trails.
- **to go hiking** means to travel up a mountain. To walk the slopes, trails, pathways, etc. You could say, **"to go hiking to the mountains"**.

If you just had a tour you could say, **"to take a tour to (into) the mountains (mountain side)"**

Comment: This answer gives an interesting differentiation, **except** these words are used more interchangeably than you've indicated here. People **do** use the word _climb_ when they are merely hiking up a mountain – particularly if they intend to reach the summit. In other words, you can indeed [climb  up Clingman's Dome](https://www.google.com/search?q="climb+Clingmans+Dome"), or your can [hike up Mount Everest](https://www.google.com/search?q="hike+Mount+Everest"). (The difference in equipment needed and technical difficulty is based more on the mountain itself, and less on the verb used.)

Comment: @J.R. I always think of **hiking** as of jouneying with merely a backpack and mostly walking along some trails, roads, paths rather than climbing up or making your way up some very steep ladder or slope. Then again there's a difference between **hiking** and **touring**.

Comment: You're not wrong – unless you try to assert that's the **only** way _hiking_ can be used.