# meanings of mountain climbing and mountaineering

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Can "mountain climbing" describe the activity of walking up a mountain without any special equipment?

And how about mountaineering?

Comment: Would [Hiking vs Climb a Mountain](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138967/hiking-vs-climb-a-mountain) – answer your question? See in particular [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138967/hiking-vs-climb-a-mountain#comment282719_138984). (I think you know *climbing* can be used to refer to a hands-free climb, it's just that you'll have to clarify anyway if it isn't evident from the context already.)

Answer (score 3):

According to [britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/sports/mountaineering) and the general google definition, mountaineering and mountain climbing mean :

> The sport or activity of climbing mountains

So they *can* describe climbing up a mountain without equipment.

Personally, I think both of those words imply that there's special equipment being used. Mountaineering is also more formal than mountain climbing.

If you want to say someone climbed a normal mountain without equipment, you could use 'hiking'. If this is an extreme case, like someone climbing Everest without equipment, you'd want to specify that there's no climbing gear involved.

Comment: Does mountain climbing necessarily involve the use of hands?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean... I think people would assume that someone climbing a mountain without any gear would be using their hands. Could you give us some context to your question?

Comment: If someone walked up a mountain without using special equipment or hands, could we say he climbed it?

Comment: It wouldn't be incorrect to say so, but if you say 'He climbed a mountain', people will assume he used his hands and/or some equipment. You would have to specify that he climbed it without using his hands if you want them to know that.

Comment: There's also the possibility of using the verb [free-climb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/free-climb). Although it's more often used for cliffs specifically, it's known to mean *without (safety) equipment*, so it would be understood in context.